# Java Name Swing Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm trying to make a java swing applet using NetBeans that will take a name like `Joe Smith` and change it to `Smith, Joe`. However, when I run my applet, it doesn't change the name. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String name = null;
        String strName = nameTextField.getText();
        if (name == "") {
            return;
        } else {
            outputLabel.setText(convertName(name));
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasComma(String name) {
        return name.indexOf(',') >= 0;
    }

    public static String convertName(String name) {
        if (hasComma(name)) {
            return name;

        } else {
            int index = name.indexOf(' ');
            String first = name.substring(0, index);
            String last = name.substring(index + 1);
            String newName = last + ", " + first;
            return newName;
        }
    }

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel nameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField nameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel outputLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton submitButton;
// End of variables declaration
```

Comment: `name` is null therefore a lot of your code will not run. I think you meant to pass `strName` to the `convertName` function and `name` becomes redundant.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! :)

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

String strName = nameTextField.getText();

should probably be

String name = nameTextField.getText();

in submitButtonActionPerformed().

Answer (score 0):

The method to compare strings is `equals`. Change code

```
name = nameTextField.getText();
if ("".equals(name) {
   return;
```